# Use my own Amazon S3 storage with TinyMCE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tinymce

I'm looking to use my own Amazon S3 storage with TinyMCE.

The only thing I have found is a 9 year old plugin with a 404 for the download page.

Has anyone done this or know how to point my /images folder to S3 storage for images?